# CORTANA is not working for me. (US-ENGLISH)

Tags: cortana

I'm currently having trouble with my window's phone. Specifically Cortana, after getting excited to hear that it was coming out (months ago) and believing it was available at the moment i updated my phone only to find out that it wasn't yet available. Finally this month my phone updates and Cortana is available. But when i try it, it says 'it's not available for my Region or Language'?
[image]

So i did some research and was advised to make sure that everything was set appropriately for English language and so forth... So i did...
[image]

Yet it still says that it's not available for my region with the language i've chosen. Is there something i'm missing here?

Please message me as soon as possible. **Thanks In Advance!**

Comment: Check if the location in ON. Location has to be ON to use cortana